# How to find parameters of negative binomial random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider $X_i \sim NB(r_i, p)$, where Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. for $1, \ldots, N$. Let $Y_i\sim Geometric (p)$.
Then,

$X_1\sim NB(r_1,p)$ satisfies $X_1 = Y_1 + \cdots +Y_{r_1}$,

$X_2\sim NB(r_2,p)$ satisfies $X_2= Y_{r_1+1} + \cdots + Y_{r_1+r_2}$,

$\ldots$

$X_N\sim NB(r_N,p)$ satisfies $X_N= Y_{r_{N-1}+1} + \cdots + Y_{r_1+\ldots+r_N}$.

Denote $Z_1=\max_{1\leq j\leq r_1}(Y_j), \ldots, Z_N=\max_{r_{N-1}+1\leq j\leq r_1+\ldots +r_N}$.

**Question:**
Is it possible to find parameter $r$ of Negative Binomial random variable $S=\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i \sim NB(r,p)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $Z_i$ are the max of $r_i$ independent geometric random variables with parameter $p$ (with the convention that $0$ is in the support). Thus $P(Z_i \leq n)=(1-(1-p)^{n+1})^{r_i}$.

This is not a geometric CDF, thus you should not expect the sum of the $Z_i$ to be negative binomial distributed.

Comment: Thank you. But how to find the $P(\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i\leq A)$ in this case?

Comment: @Forbs In general there is a "convolution sum" way to get the PMF of a sum of independent discrete random variables. Formally this looks the same as in the continuous case, if you write the density as a sum of Dirac deltas.